# Record thread events

Tags: linux, gcc, profiling, pthreads

Suppose I need to peek on a thread's state at regular intervals and record its state along the whole execution of a program. I wouldn't know how to start thinking about this. Any pointers (pun?)? I'm on Linux, using `gcc`, `phreads` and `C` and have access to all usual Linux tools. Basically, I guess I'm asking about how to build a simple profiler for threads that will tell me how long a thread has been in some or other state during the execution of the program.

I want to be able to create graphs like Threadscope does. The X axis is time, the Y axis is core/thread number and the "colors" are state: green means running, orange is garbage collection, and so on. Does this make more sense now?

[image: Threadscope image].

Comment: Hint: how would you do this in a single threaded application?

Comment: @goldilocks: I'd `printf` like mad to console, but that won't work unless I `fprintf` on each thread to a separate file. I guess I'm after doing it from the outside.

Comment: If you are worried about the reporting being interleaved, how would doing it "from the outside" change anything?  Also, you'll probably find that the interleaved reporting is more illuminating.  BTW: printf/stdout is buffered.  You should use fprintf(stderr) if you want real time console output.

Comment: @goldilocks: Thing is, I don't want to do this for each program I code, I'd like a somewhat generic solution... though I know that here, whatever I do, it will probably not be portable. I just need to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

For Linux specific solution, you might like to have a look at `/proc/<pid>/stat` and `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/stat` for process and thread statistics, respectively. Have a look at `proc(5)` manual page for full description of all the fields there (online http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html - search for `/proc/[pid]/stat`). Specifically, at least the fields `cutime` and `stime` are of interests to you. These are monotonically increasing times, so you need to remember the previously measured value to be able to produce the time spent in the process/thread during the given time slice, in order to produce the data for your graphs. (This is how `top(1)` works.)

However, for the profiler to distinguish different states makes the problem more complicated. How do the profiler distinguish that the profiled program is in which state? It seems to me the profiled program threads need to signal this in some way to the profiler. You need to have some kind of tailored solution for this state sharing (unless you can run the different states in different threads and make the distinction this way, which I doubt).

If the state transitions are done in single place (e.g. *enter GC* and *leave GC* in your example), then one way would be as follows:

1. The monitored threads would get the start and end times of the special states by using POSIX function `clock_gettime()` - with `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &tp)` you can get the process time and with `clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &tp)` you can get the thread time (both monotonically increasing, again).
2. The thread  could communicate these timings to the profiler program with some kind of IPC.
3. If the profiler application knows the thread times of entering and leaving a state, then because it knows the thread time values at the change of measuring slices, it can determine how much of the thread time is spent in the reported states within a reporting time slice (and of course here we need to adjust the start time for a state to equal the start of the next reporting time slice).
4. The time the whole process has spent on a specific state can be calculated by summing up the thread times for that state.

Note that through `/proc/<pid>/stat` or `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/stat`, the measurement accuracy is not very good (clock ticks, often units of 10ms), but I do not know other way of getting timing information from outside of the process/thread. The function `clock_gettime()` gives very accurate times (nominally nanosecond accuracy, but note that at least in some MIPS and ARM systems the accuracy is as bad as with the `stat` files under `/proc` due to unexisting implementation of accurate timer reading for these fields within Linux kernel). You also would need to do some experimentation to make sure these two timing sources really would give the same results (by reading both values from the same threads). You can of course use these `/proc/.../stat` files inside the thread, but the accuracy just is not very good unless you spend a lot of time within a state.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the direct match to profiling info produced by the haskell compiler and processed by Threadscope is, using C and GCC, the **gprof** utility (it's part of the GNU binutils).

For it to work correctly with pthreads you need each thread to trigger some timer initialization function. This can be done without modifying your code with this pthreads wrapper library: http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/gprof.html . I haven't dealt with the problem recently, it may be that something has changed and the wrapper isn't needed anymore...

As to GUI to interpret the profiling results, there is kprof (http://kprof.sourceforge.net). Unfortunately, AFAIK it doesn't produce thread duration graphs, for that you'll have to work your own solution with the textual info produced by gprof.

If you are not picky about using the "standard" solution offered by the GCC, you may wanna try this: http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/?redir=1 (didn't try it personally, but heard good opinions).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at at [Intel VTune Amplifier XE](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/) (formerly … Intel Thread Profiler) to see if it will meet your needs.
This and other Intel Linux development tools are available [free for non-commercial use](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-download/).

In the video [Using the Timeline in Intel VTune Amplifier XE](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/) showing a timeline of a multi-threaded application, at 9:20 the presenter mentions
*"...with the frame API you can programmatically mark certain events or phases in your code.  And these marks will appear on the timeline."*

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. Hangs every two minutes, the GUI is terrible, and the command line is measuring in the kb of words! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be rather difficult *build a simple profiler* simply because there are many different factors that you have to consider and system profiling is an inherently complex task, made all the more so when you are profiling a multithreaded application.  The best advice I can think of is to look at something that already exists, for example [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/).

One advantage of OProfile is that it is open source so the [source code is available](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/download/).  But beyond this I suspect that asking how to build a profiling application might be beyond the scope of what someone can answer in a SO question, which might be why this question hasn't gotten very many responses.  Hopefully looking at some example will help you get started and then perhaps if you have more focused questions you could get some more detailed responses.